# Testing sftp connections in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sftp

I have an app that makes extensive usage of SFTP protocol.

I would like to write integrations tests for it, are there any libraries that implement SFTP server functionalities in Ruby ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=sftp ?

There is a SFTP protocol implementation here: https://github.com/georgediaz88/fun_sftp and some lib to mock SFTP: https://github.com/playlouder/mock_sftp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [net-sftp](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp), also there is a bunch of related repos https://github.com/net-ssh?tab=repositories